# Как вернуть результат выполнения метода в зависимости от передаваемых ему параметров?

Tags: java

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в зависимости от значения переменной level выполнялись разные части кода и при этом возвращали результат, вот мой код, но работать отказывается :

```
private static char encode (char[]enc, int j, char n, int level) {

    if (level == 1) {
        int k = 13464 + enc.length;
        char ch2 = (char) k;
        enc[j] = ch2;
        return (enc[j]);
    }
    if (level == 2) {
        int g1 = 13464 + enc.length;
        int g2 = 13464 - enc.length;
        char ch3 = (char) g1;
        char gh3 = (char) g2;
        enc[j] = ch3;
        enc[j+1] = gh3;
        return (enc[j]);
        return (enc[j+1]);
    }
    if (level == 3) {
        int h1 = 13464 + enc.length;
        int h2 = 13464 - enc.length;
        int h3 = 'a' + enc.length;
        char hh4 = (char) h1;
        char jh4 = (char) h2;
        char kh4 = (char) h3;
        enc[j] = hh4;
        enc[j+1] = jh4;
        enc[j+2] = kh4;
        return (enc[j]);
        return (enc[j+1]);
        return (enc[j+2]);
    }
```

Comment: вы хотите вернуть один символ? или массив символов?

Comment: Два или три `return` подряд? Нет, так нельзя.

Comment: Нужно вернуть 1, 2 или 3 символа в зависимости от значения level.

Comment: Возвращайте `char[]`.

Comment: Задача состоит в том, что есть массив символов, мне нужно одни символы поменять на другие(т.е. зашифровать) и вывести их. Но зашифровать нужно в зависимости от переменной level, и задача заключается в том, что чем больше level тем больше надо выводить символов(изначально level = 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат возвращается оператором `return`. При этом после выполнения этого оператора происходит выход из метода. Пример

```
private static int test() {
  return 1;
  return 2;
  return 3;
}
```

будет всегда возвращать 1.

Если Вам нужно вернуть из метода несколько значений, то Вам нужно возвращать массив или объект

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> test() {
  ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
  res.add(1);
  res.add(2);
  res.add(3);
  return res;
}
```

Если же Вам нужно накопить результат, то передавайте накопительный буфер как параметр

```
private static void test(ArrayList<Integer> Buf) {
  Buf.add(1);
  Buf.add(2);
  Buf.add(3);
}

ArrayList<Integer> buf = new ArrayList<>;
test(buf);
test(buf);
test(buf);
```

Comment: А если это действие будет повторяться много раз, и мне нужно потом будет в итоге отобразить все списки в одной строке, то как быть?

Comment: @Dreamerk опишите задачу, а не решение

Comment: @Dreamerk Тогда нужно буфер передавать параметром

Answer (score 0):

```
private static char encode(/*бла бла бла*/, int level) {
if(level == 1) return 'f';
if(level == 2) return 'd';
}
```

Как то так, можно дать ответ на вопрос.